# Java code design bidirectional association

Tags: java, spring, associations, bidirectional

This is a question about application code design. Here is my situation:
I have a db table named *Report* which represents the amount of time of work of a user during a given month. I have a DAO to deal with database and a @Service which encapsulates dao's methods and do more stuff with reports.

In addition, I have a table *Target*, to assign goals to the users about their activities (goals can be monthly or yearly). I have again a DAO and a @Service to use these entities.

My question is about design, because i have a bidirectional association between the two services, especially for the following processes:

- The Report service needs to update the target service when a report is added, modified or deleted..
- The target service needs the report service when we need to calculate the progression of a Target

I'm refactoring my application and seeing the two beans beans who need each other makes me feel this is not so good...
Is there a way to design properly this situation (I mean the association between my two services) or should I stay with the bidirectional association?

Comment: Are you not defining the Service Interface? That way you don't have dependency on the service beans (implementations).

Comment: Yes, I use interfaces for both my services and my DAOs. But, in my implementations, I still have this "circular" link between the two classes, which is not very beautiful and hard to maintain, especially in my unit tests..

Comment: Why targets have to be mutated when reports are? Could you explain that?

Comment: When a report is modified (by changing the total time of work for example), I have to notify the Target's Service in order to update the Target object related to this report (if there is one), to update the progression (the %). This will ensure a good data consistency between the two objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem by making some changes in my *ReportDAO* and by calling it in my *TargetService*. By doing this, I could remove bidirectional association between my two services and have only an unidirectional association.